# How do I call a php file in a wordpress file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to run a php file from a wordpress php file like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$('#show').load('../get_requests.php')
}, 3000);
});
```

I get the following error when the code runs:

```
404 (Not Found)
```

'get_requests.php' is currently where all my php theme files are.

How do I get the path to 'get_requests.php'?

Comment: what do you mean by _"all my php files are"_? root files or template files?

Comment: @r_a_f The theme files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$('#show').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/get_requests.php')
}, 3000);
});
```